# redirect one file to two differents files depending on the presence of a query string

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, redirect

I'm in the process of migrating my blog to a new platform (dotclear > drupal) and I'm trying to redirect the old URLs for the RSS feeds to the new feeds.

There are only two types of feeds (articles or comments), each in two flavors (RSS or atom), so that's only 4 URLs to redirect.

My problem comes from the fact that the feeds for the comments are basically the same as for the articles, **plus** a query-string (`?type=co`). So here are the rules that I have:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/rss.php?type=co   /rss-comments.xml
Redirect 301 /blog/rss.php           /rss.xml
Redirect 301 /blog/atom.php?type=co  /rss-comments.xml
Redirect 301 /blog/atom.php          /rss.xml
```

This works fine for the articles feeds (without query-string), but the rules for the comments feeds seem to be ignored and they simply redirect to the article feed with a (useless) query-string.

So `/blog/rss.php?type=co` is rewritten to `/rss.xml?type=co` instead of `/rss-comments.xml`.

What am I doing wrong?
I tried changing the order of the rules, with the same effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match query string using `Redirect` directive. Use `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(rss|atom)\.php$ /rss-comments.xml? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(rss|atom)\.php$ /rss.xml [L,NC,R=301]
```